# Why can I not chmod a file?

Tags: permissions, nfs, chmod

```
[nathanb@ka /x/sim/nathanb/nbsim1] ls -al ,nvram
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      2097152 Jul  5  2011 ,nvram
[nathanb@ka /x/sim/nathanb/nbsim1] sudo chmod a+w ,nvram 
chmod: changing permissions of `,nvram': Operation not permitted
```

The volume is mounted `rw`, obviously, since I can modify other stuff. But even if I `su` as root, I can't `chmod` this file.

```
[root@ka /x/sim/nathanb/nbsim1] chmod +w ,nvram
chmod: changing permissions of `,nvram': Operation not permitted
```

I did an `strace` on the `chmod`, and I see this:

```
stat64(",nvram", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2097152, ...}) = 0
chmod(",nvram", 0666)                   = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Here's the output of `stat`

```
[root@ka /x/sim/nathanb/nbsim1] stat ,nvram
Name: ,nvram             Size: 2097152       Perms: 0644/-rw-r--r--
Type: Regular File     Blocks: 4120           User: 0/root
Inode: 205777           IOsize: 32768         Group: 0/root

Access Time: Sat Jul 23 09:27:31 2011         Links: 1
Modify Time: Tue Jul  5 18:36:35 2011     FS device: 28
Change Time: Sat Jul 23 09:30:35 2011       Maj/Min: 0/0
```

And just to prove that there's not weird uid stuff going on:

```
[root@ka /x/sim/nathanb/nbsim1] id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),503(mailman),21(slocate),30(gopher),500(http),14(uucp),188(xelus),16(radadmin)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tagged this under /nfs.. If that file is on an NFS filesystem, you might need to export it on the server with `no_root_squash` to allow root on the clients to change the permissions on the file system.

Comment: I think you might be on to something. This may be difficult, because I don't really control the server or the client. But I suspect that nfs and root permissions are in fact the culprit here. Unfortunately since the files are owned by root I don't have much recourse other than trying to convince IT to do their jobs and change the files themselves.

Comment: Because IT couldn't be bothered, I just created a new directory, copied all of the files owned by me, and then created a new ,nvram file and used dd to copy from the old one to the new one. Then I unlinked the old directory and put the new one in its place. Bam, problem solved. Thanks!